# Why is the running time of disjoint-sets calculated in terms of number of operations instead of size of input?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, disjoint-sets

CLRS says "we shall analyze the running time of disjoint-set in terms of two parameters:

1. n, the number of MAKE-SET operations
2. m, the total number of MAKE-SET, UNION and FIND-SET operations"

Why is this different from most analyzations of other algorithms where the complexity is calculated in terms of input size?

Comment: because it makes sense

Comment: The operations ARE the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any algorithm using the Disjoint-Set data structure will use these 3 operations. We need to analyze the runtime of all these operations with respect to input size.

Typically,

1. we starts with creating n sets (1 for every item in our input) with - 'n' MAKE-SET operations.
2. We will do MAKE-SET, UNION and FIND-SET operations as per our need. Let us bounded with a max number of operations - say 'm' (including the initial n initialisation operations).

These are the 2 numbers n, m described in CLRS. Let me rephrase it

- n - actual input size (MAKE-SET for creating initial sets)
- m - no.of operations (MAKE-SET, UNION and FIND-SET) as per algorithm.

**Per Theorem 21.14:**

To perform 'm' operations,
with disjoint-set forest with **union by rank and path compression** implementation, You will have a worst-case runtime of **O(m * α(n))**

Hope it helps!